# Can a write to std::atomic go unseen by other threads while using std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
std::atomic<int> g_atomic;

void thread0()
{
  int oldVal = 0;
  int newVal = 1;
  while (g_atomic.compare_exchange_strong(oldVal, newVal, std::memory_order_acq_rel, std::memory_order_acquire))
  {
    // forever counting from 0 to 100 until unexpected value appears
    oldVal = newVal;
    newVal = (oldVal + 1) % 100;
  };
}

void thread1()
{
  // set unexpected value
  g_atomic.store(-1, std::memory_order_release);
}

int main()
{
  g_atomic.store(0);
  std::thread t0(thread0);
  std::thread t1(thread1);
  t0.join();
  t1.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Can it happen that the write from thread1 is somehow overwritten in the loop of thread0 before it gets visible in thread0?
The program would then run forever. This does not happen in my tests however im interested if there is any guarantee saying this will always be the case.

Comment: I don't believe the write from thread1 can be missed, no. That's why these things are called atomic.

Comment: @PaulSanders, There is one case where the write from thread1 is missed:  That's the case where thread1 completes its execution before thread0 even enters the loop.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I [tested that](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FUJkhPFcpEjJLO9s) (because I found it questionable) and it appears to be untrue.

Comment: @PaulSanders, The thing about testing multi-threaded programs is, there's no way that you can force all of the myriad different ways that the loads and stores performed by the different threads could be serialized. The program behaved a certain way every time you tested it on one particular OS/version, on one particular hardware platform. But, that doesn't mean it won't behave differently on another OS, another OS version, when built with a different compiler, run on different hardware,...  Nothing in the OP's snippet _guarantees_ that thread1 won't finish before thread0 starts.

Comment: @SolomonSlow That's why I posted a link - I put a sleep in thread0 to give thread1 a chance to finish before thread0 does anything.  And when I do that I don't get the behaviour you predicted.

Comment: @PaulSanders, D'Oh! Right... 'cause thread0 never looks at the initial value of the shared variable. It just _assumes_ that the starting value will be zero... Stupid me.

Comment: @SolomonSlow No worries, we all do it.

Answer (score 4):

So, to provide a definitive answer to this, no, a write from thread1 will never be missed by thread0.

This is because `std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong` is an atomic operation so the write from thread0 either happens before this operation starts (in which case it returns `false`) or after it completes (in which case the call will fail next time round the loop).

If it was any other way, `compare_exchange_strong` would have no utility, no?

Comment: This sounds sane but as I said Im interested if there are any guarantees of this. Atomics dont guarantee that a write will be visible at certain time in other threads. Only that the write is atomic and that other writes will be visible after the atomic write itself has become visible* in the other thread. For example what i fear might happen is: if thread1 wrote something to the g_atomic, thread0 can still for some time see the old value and write something else there. Then when the caches for these threads are resolved the thread0 write is newer and takes priority.

Comment: Now the g_atomic would never get value -1 and the program would never end - Where does C++ standard prevent such execution? Is it guaranteed that all threads see the same value of an atomic at the same time? Or do somehow chronologically older writes override the newer ones in some cases?

Comment: You don't need to worry about this because the default value of `std::memory_order` is `std::memory_order_seq_cst` for both operations and this ensures, in effect, that all threads see the same value at once.

Comment: Ok this is a fair point, for some reason i thought the default is memory_order_acq_rel. The one you mention puts a memory fence after every read/write so these behave just like one thread was doing those. However i still feel that even for memory_order_acq_rel there has to be some sort of guarantee.

Comment: Yes I think so, by virtue of the variable itself being atomic.  We need to attract the attention of @PeterCordes, he knows all this stuff.

Comment: I edited the question, hope i put in the right ones. We summon you mighty @PeterCordes to answer this question

Comment: @Katz389 The scenario you describe cannot happen, and Paul is correct to say the program will terminate. When a cache-coherent processor running thread0 runs its CAS loop, it has the cacheline in Modified mode. When thread1 intervenes with its write, it results in an RFO (Read For Ownership) on the bus, and snooping logic sends that cacheline to thread1’s processor in Exclusive mode, while Invalidate'ing it in thread0’s processor’s cache. The thread1 then completes its write to the cacheline, switching it to Modified mode. Thread0’s next CAS will wait to reaquire the cacheline; No stale reads.

Comment: @Katz389 More on this protocol (called MESI) [here](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/cache-coherency/).